# Stripe Puerto Rico Street Addresses Not Accepted

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

According to Stripe, Puerto Rico addresses are the exception for outlying territories. However most Puerto Rico addresses I submit are rejected when creating a new connect account. Example

```
{
  city: "Rio Grande",
  country: "US"
  line1: "State Road 187 Kilometer 4.2",
  line2: null,
  postal_code: "00745",
  state: "PR"
}
```

Update - Moving Kilometer 4.2 to line 2 does not return a success response. The error received from Stripe is code: `invalid_street_address`, reason: `The provided street address cannot be found. Please verify the street name and number are correct in "State Road 187"`, requirement: `individual.address.line1`

Comment: I think you'll have to talk to their support and ask them directly. What's the validation error you're getting?

Comment: Just a guess: move `Kilometer 4.2` to the `line2` field.

Comment: Do Stripe payment boxes still autocomplete addresses? You could pretend to make a payment from that address and see what you can autocomplete to?

Answer (score 0):

You should write into [Support](https://support.stripe.com/contact/email) about this.